# Changing a property of an object in child component using VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple question but I can't find the answer to it. 
This code (that belongs to a child component? is a good practice?

```
 export default {
  name: 'Wish',
  props: ['wish'],
  data () {
    return {
      isEditing: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    completeWish () {
      this.wish.done = true
    },
   ...
```

Or I should update the done property of wish object in the parent using emit?

Thanks

Comment: This is a design choice. Sometimes you want to update the object in the child, sometimes you want to emit a change.

Comment: Props are read-only. (or at least you shouldn't try to change them)

Comment: Is it clearer to you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive

if you want add or change property use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) like this:

```
this.$set(this.wish, 'done', true)
```

see example App:
https://3xyx386q65.codesandbox.io/setProps

see example code (open *components/setProps/childComponent.vue*):
https://codesandbox.io/s/3xyx386q65

**note!  `wish` init as Object! See *components/setProps/setProps.vue* in example code**

Answer (score 10):

As Amade mentioned is a bad practice.

You should use [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) in order to accomplish it properly from a design point of view.

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Wish',
    props: ['wish'],
    methods: {
      completeWish () {
        this.$emit('wish-is-completed')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And then in parent you have `v-on:wish-is-completed="handleCompletedWish"` like:

```
// Parent template
<template>
  <wish v-on:wish-is-completed="handleCompletedWish"></wish>
</template>
```

EDIT:

I understand the answer was downvoted because **you actually are able to mutate properties of props (not a direct prop reference) and don't get a warn when you do that**.

Does it mean you should do that?

No.

Props are created for one-directional data flow purpose. When you mutate props to notify a parent of something, it quickly leads to having hard to maintain state changes, because they are not implicit. Use events for child->parent communication as official documentation suggest in such cases.

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and
> the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to
> the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child
> components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can
> make your app’s data flow harder to understand.

Comment: "it quickly leads to having hard to maintain state changes". I keep reading this everywhere but can anyone provide an actual example of this leading to issues? I have yet to come across one.

Answer (score 1):

[Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) advise against mutating the props in the child component:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand.
>
> In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. **This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component.** If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

So based on this I would tend to say it's a bad practice.

Comment: Vue will not warn you if you change a property of an object passed in as a prop.

Comment: It is phrased poorly. They mean that you should not attempt to mutate the reference of a prop. If you have a prop `wish`, the docs mean that you should not attempt to do things like `this.wish = 'a new wish'`

Comment: At the end of the section I quoted it says: "Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child will affect parent state". Doesn't it go against the 'one-way data flow' principle?

Comment: @Bert you still should not do that because props are for **one-directional data flow** purpose. You won't get a warn but using it quickly leads to having hard to maintain state changes, because they are not implicit. Always use events for child->parent communication.

Comment: As I said under the question, it's a design decision. This is an opinionated issue. There's no right answer.

Comment: @Bert yep. OO example: you can pass args to a constructor **to build an object** and then notify caller side through those args that something has happened just because you can. You're right, that's a design decision.